# WordPress converts the hyphen to the dash in the title automatically

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress blog, i found it would convert the hyphen character to the dash character automatically.

For example, I create a blog post with the following TITLE:

Wikipedia - the free encyclopedia

However, when I checked the post, I found the title was displayed as:

Wikipedia – the free encyclopedia

And I check the source code of HTML:

```
<title>Wikipedia &#8211; the free encyclopedia</title>
```

So, The hyphen (-) was changed to the dash (–), why was this?

How to disable such conversion?

Comment: You may have better luck asking WordPress questions on the WordPress Stack Exchange, where a [similar question has already been answered](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60379/how-to-prevent-automatic-conversion-of-dashes-to-ndash). I think it's likely that you're seeing the results of the basic [wptexturize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) filter running over your content.